# How to Reduce time to create view dynamically in android?

Tags: android

Hi I am studying android.

I make mine sweeper game now.

Getting the level info of game from the user, I try creating views dynamically in android for the first time.

When I click the button "READY", buttons are created dynamically.

When an easy game is selected, 60 buttons, when intermediate, 81 buttons, and when difficult, 135 buttons are created.

But the activity stops really frequently.

I want to know more reliable way to make views.

Here is code to create them. Thanks a lot

```
public void makeMineFarm(int level) {
        int rowNum = EASY_ROW;
        int colNum = EASY_COLUMN;

        switch (level) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                rowNum = MEDIUM_ROW;
                colNum = MEDIUM_COLUMN;
                break;
            case 3:
                rowNum = DIFFICULT_ROW;
                colNum = DIFFICULT_COLUMN;
                break;
        }

        tableRow = new TableRow[rowNum];
        buttons = new MineButton[rowNum][colNum];

        int[] valArr = getMineValue(rowNum, colNum);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
            tableRow[i] = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tableRow[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {

                buttons[i][j] = new MineButton(this);


                TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
                lp.width = 120;
                lp.height = 120;
                lp.setMargins(-5, -5, -5, -5);
                buttons[i][j].setLayoutParams(lp);
                buttons[i][j].setTextSize(18);


                if (valArr[colNum * i + j] == -1) {
                    buttons[i][j].setValue("@");
                } else {
                    buttons[i][j].setValue(Integer.toString(valArr[colNum * i + j]));
                }

                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(new OnMineButtonClickListener(this, buttons[i][j]));


                tableRow[i].addView(buttons[i][j]);
            }

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow[i]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: looking at your heading, runtime view creation is not faster, xml declaration is...

Comment: @SarthakMittal Thanks!!!!